# Inserting into multiple tables with identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Transactions] ([PartnerId], [TransactionId], [ver], [InsertedBy], [InsertedDateTime], [SavedBy], [SavedDateTime])
    SELECT     
        [PartnerId], [TransactionId], [ver], [InsertedBy],
        [InsertedDateTime], [SavedBy], [SavedDateTime] 
    FROM        
        @parTransaction;

SET @TransactionID = @@IDENTITY;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Remittances] ([TransactionID], [RemittanceTransactionId],[InsertedBy], [InsertedDateTime], [SavedBy], [SavedDateTime])
    SELECT 
        @TransactionID, [RemittanceTransactionId], [InsertedBy],
        [InsertedDateTime], [SavedBy], [SavedDateTime]
    FROM         
        @parRemittance;

SET @RemittanceID = @@IDENTITY ;
```

My issue here is when there is no record to insert into `Remittance` table, `@RemittanceID` is getting the identity value of the `Transactions` table.

So let's say identity value inserted in transaction table is 1, and there are no records in `Remittance` table, then `@TransactionID` and `@RemittanceID` both are set to 1, but I want the `@TransactionID` value to be set as 1 and `@RemittanceID` as null.

Is there any way so that if there is no record inserted into `Remittance` table, `@RemittanceID` value should set to NULL.

Comment: You should look into using OUTPUT instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql And if you are going to stick with two separate statements you should be using SCOPE_IDENTITY instead. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Comment: I would also recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `@@ROWCOUNT` here to determine if an update occurred within the last statement.

```
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Remittances]
                           ([TransactionID],[RemittanceTransactionId],[InsertedBy],[InsertedDateTime],[SavedBy],[SavedDateTime])
               SELECT 
                            @TransactionID,[RemittanceTransactionId],[InsertedBy],[InsertedDateTime],[SavedBy],[SavedDateTime]
               FROM         @parRemittance;

               SET         @RemittanceID =  @@IDENTITY ;


     IF(@@ROWCOUNT=0) SET @RemittanceID = NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these two functions:

1. IDENT_CURRENT('tablename')

   - Returns the last identity value generated for a specified table or view. The last identity value generated can be for any session and any scope.
2. SCOPE_IDENTITY()

   - Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch. +

With #1 above, keep in mind it could get the identity value from some other session if your procedure can run concurrently.

Probably, you could use both together.

Comment: I agree with Sean. I think OUTPUT would solve your problem. You could just declare a new table variable with one column and insert the identity column value in the table variable